# Why does the front page show my name for last activity even when I didn't perform anything recently?

Tags: bug, editing

I didn't edit/answer this question right now:

- [How to install Skype with Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293693/how-to-install-skype-with-13-04)

However, I did answer the question on May 16, but right now it's May 25.

**How come it's showing that it has been edited by me?**

> [image: front page]

Following is the image of my answer to that question:

> [image: my answer]

And a full screen image with date:

> [image: full screen image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also noticed this, and it seems to happen when a question gets reopened, it shows the last person to interact with the question ( besides the closing/reopening  activity) as the one that currently changed something.

I suppose the reason might be so the question gets bumped to the top of the list.

If you look the in the edit history the last activity was the following, which happened right around the time it has near your name.

> Post Reopened by RolandiXor♦

Which is the name I would expect to see for the last edit/change/activity, except that activity is not directly changing the question or answers.

Comment: Got it ....thank you

Comment: Oh, I think it was just the other day tahat it happened to me on this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/299293/how-to-apt-get-dist-upgrade-an-asus-eeepc-1005ha-using-ubuntu-10-04-4-lts-netb  , maybe someone should make a post on meta so about it.